# How Can I Scroll the Images In QML Automatically?

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` Containing only `Image`s. I assigned the `orientation` of `ListView` as horizontal Direction. How can I change, i.e. scroll, the images automatically with some time gap?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Timer`. When it is triggered, update the `currentIndex` of the `ListView`. This will scroll automatically with default animations. Finally, according to the documentation, [`positionViewAtIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#positionViewAtIndex-method) is

> The **correct** way to bring an item into view is with positionViewAtIndex

Indeed the method provides a more fine-grained control over the appearance of `Item`s via the `PositionMode` parameter. See the documentation for further details.

Minimal example:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 15
    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: 10
        delegate: Text {
            width: 40
            id: name
            text: index
        }
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 500
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            //list.currentIndex +=  1         // this...
            //list.incrementCurrentIndex()    // ...or this!
            //list.positionViewAtIndex(list.currentIndex, ListView.Center)
        }
    }
}
```